# Integrate SOAP API in php

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to integrate SOAP/HTTP POST/XML API for car registration online lookup fuction into my website, I haven't got idea how to insert this script in php file, all the time getting errors.

Script

```html
SOAP 1.1

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /api/reg.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.regcheck.org.uk
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Check"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Check xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <RegistrationNumber>string</RegistrationNumber>
      <username>string</username>
    </Check>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CheckResult>
        <vehicleJson>string</vehicleJson>
        <vehicleXml>string</vehicleXml>
        <numberOfSeats>string</numberOfSeats>
        <carValue>string</carValue>
        <immobiliser>string</immobiliser>
        <vehicleData>
          <ABICode type="NCName" />
          <Description type="NCName" />
          <RegistrationYear type="NCName" />
          <ManufactureYearFrom type="NCName" />
          <ManufactureYearTo type="NCName" />
          <CarMake type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </CarMake>
          <CarModel type="NCName" />
          <BodyStyle type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </BodyStyle>
          <EngineSize type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </EngineSize>
          <NumberOfDoors type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </NumberOfDoors>
          <Transmission type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </Transmission>
          <FuelType type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </FuelType>
          <MakeDescription type="NCName" />
          <ModelDescription type="NCName" />
          <Immobiliser type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </Immobiliser>
          <NumberOfSeats type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </NumberOfSeats>
          <IndicativeValue type="NCName" />
          <DriverSide type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </DriverSide>
        </vehicleData>
      </CheckResult>
    </CheckResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
SOAP 1.2

The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /api/reg.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.regcheck.org.uk
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Check xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <RegistrationNumber>string</RegistrationNumber>
      <username>string</username>
    </Check>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <CheckResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CheckResult>
        <vehicleJson>string</vehicleJson>
        <vehicleXml>string</vehicleXml>
        <numberOfSeats>string</numberOfSeats>
        <carValue>string</carValue>
        <immobiliser>string</immobiliser>
        <vehicleData>
          <ABICode type="NCName" />
          <Description type="NCName" />
          <RegistrationYear type="NCName" />
          <ManufactureYearFrom type="NCName" />
          <ManufactureYearTo type="NCName" />
          <CarMake type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </CarMake>
          <CarModel type="NCName" />
          <BodyStyle type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </BodyStyle>
          <EngineSize type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </EngineSize>
          <NumberOfDoors type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </NumberOfDoors>
          <Transmission type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </Transmission>
          <FuelType type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </FuelType>
          <MakeDescription type="NCName" />
          <ModelDescription type="NCName" />
          <Immobiliser type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </Immobiliser>
          <NumberOfSeats type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </NumberOfSeats>
          <IndicativeValue type="NCName" />
          <DriverSide type="NCName">
            <CurrentValue xsi:nil="true" />
            <CurrentTextValue xsi:nil="true" />
          </DriverSide>
        </vehicleData>
      </CheckResult>
    </CheckResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP GET

The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

GET /api/reg.asmx/Check?RegistrationNumber=string&username=string HTTP/1.1
Host: www.regcheck.org.uk
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vehicle xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <vehicleJson>string</vehicleJson>
  <vehicleXml>string</vehicleXml>
  <numberOfSeats>string</numberOfSeats>
  <carValue>string</carValue>
  <immobiliser>string</immobiliser>
  <vehicleData>
    <ABICode type="NCName" />
    <Description type="NCName" />
    <RegistrationYear type="NCName" />
    <ManufactureYearFrom type="NCName" />
    <ManufactureYearTo type="NCName" />
    <CarMake type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </CarMake>
    <CarModel type="NCName" />
    <BodyStyle type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </BodyStyle>
    <EngineSize type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </EngineSize>
    <NumberOfDoors type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </NumberOfDoors>
    <Transmission type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </Transmission>
    <FuelType type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </FuelType>
    <MakeDescription type="NCName" />
    <ModelDescription type="NCName" />
    <Immobiliser type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </Immobiliser>
    <NumberOfSeats type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </NumberOfSeats>
    <IndicativeValue type="NCName" />
    <DriverSide type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </DriverSide>
  </vehicleData>
</Vehicle>
HTTP POST

The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /api/reg.asmx/Check HTTP/1.1
Host: www.regcheck.org.uk
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

RegistrationNumber=string&username=string
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vehicle xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <vehicleJson>string</vehicleJson>
  <vehicleXml>string</vehicleXml>
  <numberOfSeats>string</numberOfSeats>
  <carValue>string</carValue>
  <immobiliser>string</immobiliser>
  <vehicleData>
    <ABICode type="NCName" />
    <Description type="NCName" />
    <RegistrationYear type="NCName" />
    <ManufactureYearFrom type="NCName" />
    <ManufactureYearTo type="NCName" />
    <CarMake type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </CarMake>
    <CarModel type="NCName" />
    <BodyStyle type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </BodyStyle>
    <EngineSize type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </EngineSize>
    <NumberOfDoors type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </NumberOfDoors>
    <Transmission type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </Transmission>
    <FuelType type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </FuelType>
    <MakeDescription type="NCName" />
    <ModelDescription type="NCName" />
    <Immobiliser type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </Immobiliser>
    <NumberOfSeats type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </NumberOfSeats>
    <IndicativeValue type="NCName" />
    <DriverSide type="NCName">
      <CurrentValue type="NCName" />
      <CurrentTextValue type="NCName" />
    </DriverSide>
  </vehicleData>
</Vehicle>
```

Comment: Those are example SOAP requests. What do you mean you were trying to insert them into a PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a little bit research. There are 2 ways you can go about this.

1) You can use CURL and mimic these HTTP requests, and simply send the string over after constructing the Headers

2) You can use SOAPClient which is already implemented in PHP 5.0.1 and higher(http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php). The website you are integrating with must have a WSDL file that will allow you to use it with SOAPClient in an object oriented matter.

If you research the subjects above, you should have an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I used the website "wsdltophp.com" to generate proxy classes for this webservice "[www.regcheck.org.uk](http://www.regcheck.org.uk)"

https://www.wsdltophp.com/Wsdls/8a71627601a684624c5694104cce023f/RegCheck-1-0-1-1-1-1-0-0-0-0

You can download all the files as a zip here; https://app.box.com/s/tepsfd6t0cahfdi9ivgnj305qocxrrt6

or alternatively, you can use a HTTP GET request, It's possible to call that web service via a HTTP GET request as follows;

```
<?php
$username = 'Your username here';
$regNumber = 'SK08KPT';
$xmlData = file_get_contents("https://www.regcheck.org.uk/api/reg.asmx/Check?RegistrationNumber=" . $regNumber  ."&username=" . $username);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlData);    
$strJson = $xml->vehicleJson;    
$json = json_decode($strJson);    
print_r($json->Description);    
?>
```

Not as elegant as a SOAP call, but simpler.